# Is there a way to use property get and set notation in a JS function class?

Tags: javascript, function, getter-setter

Is there a way in JavaScript's constructor functions to use getter and setter syntax for properties?

Here is an example of my ***desired*** syntax:

```js
function DemoClass()
{
 var mFooProperty = 0;
  
 get FooProperty()
 {
  return mFooProperty;
 }

 set FooProperty(value)
 {
  mFooProperty = value;
 }
}

var anInstance = new DemoClass();
console.log(anInstance.FooProperty);
anInstance.FooProperty = 42;
console.log(anInstance.FooProperty);
```

Comment: Your title was too long, I wanted to make it short. Just rolled it back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to keep the real storage for that property as a private variable, you'd have to use an Object API to define the getter and setter in the constructor:

```
function DemoClass() {
  var mFooProperty = 0;
  Object.defineProperties(this, {
    fooProperty: {
      get: function() { return mFooProperty; },
      set: function(value) { mFooProperty = value; }
    }
  });
}
```

Now when you construct an instance, the instance will appear to have a property called "fooProperty". Referencing the value of the property will invoke the "getter" function, and setting the value calls the "setter":

```
var d = new DemoClass();
console.log(d.fooProperty); // calls getter 0
d.fooProperty = 3;          // calls setter
console.log(d.fooProperty); // 3
```

Comment: This works.  It maintains the private nature of constructor function and syntactic sugar of getter and setter methods.

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of a class in Javascript and set the properties as a class instance and then use getters/setters like

```js
class DemoClass {

    constructor() {
       this.mFooProperty = 0;
    }
  
 get FooProperty() {
  return this.mFooProperty;
 }

 set FooProperty(value) {
  this.mFooProperty = value;
 }
}

var anInstance = new DemoClass();
console.log(anInstance.FooProperty);
anInstance.FooProperty = 42;
console.log(anInstance.FooProperty);
```

According to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes):

> The bodies of class declarations and class expressions are executed in
>   [`strict mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) i.e. constructor, static and prototype methods,
>   getter and setter functions are executed in strict mode.

Comment: Note that this approach means that `mFooProperty` will be visible externally.

Comment: The problem with this approach is in the public access of mFooProperty.  The following is legal but undesired:  anInstance.mFooProperty = 13;